# Python 3: How can object be instance of type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

In Python 3, `object` is an instance of `type` and `type` is also an instance of `object`!

How is it possible that each class is derived from the other?

Any implementation details?

I checked this using `isinstance(sub, base)`, which, according to Python documentation, checks if sub class is derived from base class:

```
isinstance(object, type)
Out[1]: True

isinstance(type, object)
Out[2]: True
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is one of the edge cases in Python:

- Everything in Python is an object, so since `object` is the base type of everything, `type` (being something in Python) is an instance of `object`.
- Since `object` is the base *type* of everything, `object` is also a *type*, which makes `object` an instance of `type`.

Note that this relationship is nothing you can replicate with your own *things* in Python. It’s a single exception that is built into the language.

---

On the implementation side, the two names are represented by `PyBaseObject_Type` (for `object`) and `PyType_Type` (for `type`).

When you use `isinstance`, the type check—in the very last step, after everything else has failed—is done by [`type_is_subtype_base_chain`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1dd4f473c627/Objects/typeobject.c#l1344):

```
type_is_subtype_base_chain(PyTypeObject *a, PyTypeObject *b)
{
    do {
        if (a == b)
            return 1;
        a = a->tp_base;
    } while (a != NULL);

    return (b == &PyBaseObject_Type);
}
```

This essentially keeps going up the type hierarchy of `a` and checks the resulting type against `b`. If it cannot find one, then the last resort is to check whether `b` is actually `object` in which case the function returns true: since everything is an object. So the “everything is an instance of `object`” part is actually hardcoded into the instance check.

And as for why `object` is a `type`, this is actually even simpler because it’s simply defined that way in the [declaration of `PyBaseObject_Type`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/1dd4f473c627/Objects/typeobject.c#l3294):

```
PyTypeObject PyBaseObject_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "object",                                   /* tp_name */
    sizeof(PyObject),                           /* tp_basicsize */
    …
```

The `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT` essentially sets the core type information stuff, including the base type, which is `PyType_Type`.

There are actually two more consequences of this relationship:

- Since everything is an object, `object` is also an instance of `object`: `isinstance(object, object)`
- Since `PyType_Type` is also implemented with the same `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT`, `type` is also a type: `isinstance(type, type)`.

Comment: I'm sure you could emulate this behaviour with virtual subclasses.