# Why does type subclass object?

Tags: python, class, oop, types, python-datamodel

I am learning the Python data model. I have read [this article](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html).

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995472/python-3-how-can-object-be-instance-of-type) @poke answered how the built-in function `isinstance` works. It explained:

```
>>> isinstance(type, object) #Because type.__base__==object
True
>>> isinstance(object, object)
True
```

So my question is why `type.__base__==object`? and `issubclass(object,object)==True` when `object.__bases__==()` ?

Is it just for keeping unification of "everything is a instance of `object`"?

Comment: `PyObject_HEAD` is not the same thing as `object`.

Comment: There ARE a number of good questions buried in this.  I'd suggest opening a new question (or questions) and making your core questions more clear.