# Get complete list of all possible Class Attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, python-2.x

Is there a way, given a simple Class, to output all the possible attributes for it? Standard attributes like `__class__` and `__doc__` ***and*** [special read only attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes) like `__mro__`, `__bases__` et al. Generally, ***all*** present attributes?

Considering the most simplistic case for a Class:

```
class myClass:
    pass
```

The `dir()`, `vars()` and `inspect.getmembers()` all exclude certain `builtin` attributes. The most complete list is offered by using `myClass.__dir__(MyClass)` which, while adding built in attributes, excludes user defined attributes of `MyClass`, for example:

```
In [3]: set(MyClass.__dir__(MyClass)) - set(dir(MyClass))
Out[3]: 
{'__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__',
 '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__dictoffset__',
 '__flags__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__',
 '__mro__', '__name__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__',
 '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__text_signature__',
 '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro'}
```

According to one of the added similar questions, this is not possible. If presently still not possible, what is the rationale behind "hiding" **certain** attributes like `__bases__` (from standard calls to `dir(), vars() & inspect` and not ones like `__name__`?

---

#### Similar Questions:

- [How to get a complete list of object's methods and attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes)

  > This is the most likely to be labeled as a duplicate, ***but***, it is old and mostly regarding `Python 2.x`. The accepted answer is that there isn't a way but it was provided in 08'. The most recent answer in 12' suggests `dir()` for new style classes.
- [Print all properties of a Python Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969806/print-all-properties-of-a-python-class)

  > Similar title, different content.
- [Getting attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class)

  > Offers `dir()` and `inspect` solutions.
- [Get all object attributes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886493/get-all-object-attributes-in-python)

  > Again, proposing `dir()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a complete list of object's methods and attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191010/how-to-get-a-complete-list-of-objects-methods-and-attributes)

Comment: You didn't even read my question, did you?

Comment: The 2.x answer is not outdated. You can write `__getattr__` to do literally anything. I have several classes where `__getattr__` says that a URL needs to be queried - there's no way to know in advance what that URL will return or not, so there's no way of generating an exhaustive list of attributes. `__dir__` will return most attributes most of the time, but because of the dynamic nature of getting and setting attributes, there's really no way to get the complete list all of the time. As for why `__bases__` is hidden but not `__name__`, I couldn't tell you.

Comment: This is why the question has been tagged as `Python 3.x` and not `Python 2.x`.

Comment: That other question was generally about Python. It applies to 2.x and 3.x. This question is a sub-question of that. The answer is already there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) is basically a convenience method, it is not supposed to return everything, what it basically does is that it recursively returns everything found in the dictionary of a class and its bases.

[PyPy's implementation of `dir()`](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/c9976e50bbb80cab189ff525b2c6d2643d48ee50/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_inspect.py?at=missing-os-functions&fileviewer=file-view-default#app_inspect.py-26) is quite easy to understand:

```
def dir(*args):
    ...
    elif isinstance(obj, (types.TypeType, types.ClassType)):
        # Don't look at __class__, as metaclass methods would be confusing.
        return sorted(_classdir(obj))
    ...

def _classdir(klass):
    """Return a set of the accessible attributes of class/type klass.

    This includes all attributes of klass and all of the base classes
    recursively.
    """
    names = set()
    ns = getattr(klass, '__dict__', None)
    if ns is not None:
        names.update(ns)
    bases = getattr(klass, '__bases__', None)
    if bases is not None:
        # Note that since we are only interested in the keys, the order
        # we merge classes is unimportant
        for base in bases:
            names.update(_classdir(base))
    return names
```

As each class basically inherits from `object` you will see some dunder methods included because they are actually part of `object`'s dictionary:

```
>>> class A(object):
    pass
...
>>> set(dir(A)) == set(list(object.__dict__) + list(A.__dict__))
True
```

---

> Now what about `__bases__` and other missing items?

First of all `object` itself is an instance of something, [well it's bit of a mess actually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31995472/846892):

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
>>> issubclass(type, object)
True
>>> issubclass(object, type)
False
>>> type.mro(object)
[<type 'object'>]
>>> type.mro(type)
[<type 'type'>, <type 'object'>]
```

So, all of the attributes like `__bases__`, `__ge__` etc are actually part of `type`:

```
>>> list(type.__dict__)
['__module__', '__abstractmethods__', '__getattribute__', '__weakrefoffset__', '__dict__', '__lt__', '__init__', '__setattr__', '__subclasses__', '__new__', '__base__', '__mro__', 'mro', '__dictoffset__', '__call__', '__itemsize__', '__ne__', '__instancecheck__', '__subclasscheck__', '__gt__', '__name__', '__eq__', '__basicsize__', '__bases__', '__flags__', '__doc__', '__delattr__', '__le__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__ge__']
```

Hence when we do `A.__bases__` we are actually looking up a [descriptor on type of `A`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-howto-guide), i.e `type`:

```
>>> A.__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
>>> type(A).__dict__['__bases__'].__get__(A, type)
(<type 'object'>,)
```

So, as `A` is an instance of `type` these methods are not part of its own dictionary but its type's dictionary.

```
>> class A(object):
...     spam = 'eggs'
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.foo = 100
>>> a.bar = 200
>>> a.__dict__
{'foo': 100, 'bar': 200}
>>> A.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'spam': 'eggs'})
```

As, `type` is a subclass of `object`, the `dir()` call on `type` will contain some items from `object`:

```
>>> set(dir(type)) - set(type.__dict__)
set(['__reduce_ex__', '__str__', '__format__', '__reduce__', '__class__', '__subclasshook__', '__sizeof__'])
```

Comment: I see, so my initial assumption that they are hidden is pretty wrong, attributes like `__bases__` are just inherited from `type` and so calling a function like `dir()` on a subclass of `type` just won't return the inherited attributes. Also, regarding the existence of a function that fetches everything, I'm guessing the short answer is that if I want a function like that, better implement it myself because it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @DimitrisJim Almost correct, but "`dir()` on a subclass of type" should be "`dir()` on an instance of `type`", for example if you create a metaclass that has some attributes then its instances(aka classes) won't have those attributes visible to us but the attribute access will still work. No, there's no such function available, at least not in standard library.

Comment: O.k, gotcha with that. The only thing I still don't get (which maybe I should ask as another question) is, given again an empty class definition, why certain inherited attributes from `type` like `__ ge__` are visible in `__dict__` and or `__dir__` and others like `__bases__` are not.

Comment: @DimitrisJim Because they are part of object's `__dict__`, and other properties like `__bases__` are not: `set(dir(A)) == set(list(object.__dict__) + list(A.__dict__))`. **Python 2:** http://ideone.com/TR0YPh ; **Python 3:** http://ideone.com/tmlHfW

Comment: Thanks, Ashwini. I think I've got it. I'll ask a related question if I get lost again. Good day!