# How to test if a class had explicietly defined a __gt__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to test whether a costume class had explicitly defined an attribute like `__gt__`? To put things in context consider these two classes:

```
class myclass1:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if type(other) is int:
            return self.val > other
        else:
            return self.val > other.val


class myclass2:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

Since I've defined an inequality attribute only for `myclass1` and not for `myclass2` calling

```
x1 = myclass1(5); x2 = myclass2(2)
x1 > x2
x2 < x1
```

will use `myclass1.__gt__` in both cases. Had I defined `myclass2.__lt__`, the last line would have invoked it. But I didn't. So `x1`'s `__gt__` takes hold in both calls. I think I understand this (but comments are welcomed).

So my question: Is there a way to know which inequalities had been explicitly defined for a custom class? Because

```
hasattr(x2, '__gt__')
```

returns `True` anyway.

Comment: You can use dir(className), which will provide you all the methods and attribute belongs to your class.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - No. This will enlist `__lt__` whether I explicitly defined it or not.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare See how `dir()` works: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33087797/846892

Comment: I'm using 3.4 and if you do `type(ClassName.__gt__).__name__` you get `function` if one is defined and `wrapper_descriptor` if one has not. This holds for inheritance as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check inside the `__dict__` for each class:

```
'__gt__' in x2.__class__.__dict__
Out[23]: False

'__gt__' in x1.__class__.__dict__
Out[24]: True
```

Or, using built-ins in order to not rely on dunders:

```
'__gt__' in vars(type(x1))
Out[31]: True

'__gt__' in vars(type(x2))
Out[32]: False
```

Comment: Note that this will fail to detect the case where a class inherits a `__gt__` from a superclass (rather than defining it itself).  It's unclear whether this would count as "explicit" according to the question.

Comment: What if `__gt__` is not defined in the class itself but it is being inherited from a parent class? I would recommend comparing: `type(x2).__gt__` and `object.__gt__`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Great. Seems like an efficient way.