# Are __eq__, __ne__, __hash__ attributes of object type?

Tags: python

In the below list of attributes,

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

`__eq__`, `__ne__` & `__hash__` are not shown as attributes. They are attributes of meta class `type`

```
>>> dir(type)
    [... '__eq__', .... '__hash__', ... '__ne__', ...]
>>>
```

and `object` is not in `is-a` relation with `type`

```
>>> issubclass(object, type)
    False
>>> issubclass(type, object)
    True
```

But, I see these attributes part of `object`,

```
>>> object.__eq__
    <method-wrapper '__eq__' of type object at 0x905b80>
>>> object.__ne__
    <method-wrapper '__ne__' of type object at 0x905b80>
>>> object.__hash__
    <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'object' objects>
>>>
```

This allows,

```
class X(object):
   pass
```

`class X` to override these attributes.

---

**Question:**

Are these attributes of `object`?

Comment: `type` is "the metaclass" of `object`. :)

Comment: `isinstance(object, type)` returns `True`

Comment: Related: [Get complete list of all possible Class Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087797/get-complete-list-of-all-possible-class-attributes)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Hmmm 1) `isinstance(X, type)` is also returning true.  `object` is not subclass of `type` but `X` is subclass of `type`. What is going on here? 2) Why should `X` inherit attributes of `type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in `type` define how a class behaves, the methods in `object` implement how instances behave.

Using your subclass of `object`:

```
class X(object):
    pass
```

Then

```
X == X
```

will call `type.__eq__(X, X)`

But:

```
X() == X()
```

will call `object.__eq__(X, X)`

At least as long you don't override these [magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) (either in your `X` directly or when you define your own metaclass for `X`).

---

If you "go meta", then it's important to know that metaclasses are to classes what instances are to classes:

```
>>> isinstance(object, type)   # class & metaclass
True

>>> isinstance(X(), X)         # instance & class
True
```

Answer (score 1):

They are part of the data model customization, called 'magic methods', you have to think of them as an interface for interaction with python functionalities.
Here is all the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) relating this.